# SQL UPDATE not working and no error is thrown

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm coding a program in `Visual studio` windows forms, and my `SQL UPDATE`statement isn't working, and there are no `errors` thrown. Here are my codes:

```
  string strConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
         ["Brownie.Properties.Settings.BrownieDB2ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        SqlConnection sqlconnect = new SqlConnection(strConnection);

        string strSQL = "UPDATE Cargo SET Jobdone = 'Yes' WHERE (DriverID IN (SELECT DriverID FROM Driver WHERE (CardID = @a)))";

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(strSQL, sqlconnect);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", momentcardid);

        try
        {
            //step 3: open connection
            sqlconnect.Open();
            //step 4: execute command
            int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (result > 0)
                MessageBox.Show("Job has been successfully updated");
            else
                MessageBox.Show("Job update is unsuccessful");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            //step 5: close connection
            sqlconnect.Close();
        }
```

I tested out this code on the Query Testing function provided by `Visual studio` under `Server Explorer (Right click database > Right click table name > New Query)`, placed the value `momentcardid` for testing and it was able to update successfully into the database.

However when I tried to run the codes on winform, it does not update into the database. There is no error thrown as well. It even displays the message box `Job has been updated successfully`

I'm really not sure what is wrong, I hope someone can help me figure out!

Comment: Try removing `(` after WHERE, like this: `WHERE DriverID IN (SELECT DriverID FROM Driver WHERE (CardID = @a))`

Comment: @un-lucky that won't change anything; the brackets are correctly balanced, and the syntax shown is perfectly valid, and semantically equivalent to the same without the part around the predicate

Comment: I just tried, it doesn't work

Comment: momentcardid is set with value? Can you debug and check that?

Comment: What is the value of `momentcardid`? What makes you think it does not update the database (be as explicit as possible)?

Comment: @MarcGravell: Sounds correct. Thanks for correcting me

Comment: Did you verify you are using the correct connection string? The code looks OK and as it finds affected rows, it either is updating a different database or a different row than you might think.

Comment: try add  `cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;`

Comment: Put a break point on cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue and copy the SQL command along with the value of momentcardid. Open up a SQL query window from Management Studio (or whatever it's called these days) paste the SQL command in - tweak it a little so it doesn't use parameters and just make sure it actually does what you think it does.

Comment: @VonAaron that's the default

Comment: Side note: You should use the using statement with all disposable objects: SqlConnection, SqlCommand etc`. Other then that your code seems fine to me, and I think Marc's answer is correct.

Comment: Do a trace in sql server profiler to see what query you are actually getting.
 Do you have any triggers on the table. If your trigger does not have NOCOUNT ON, then the rows affected by the trigger will be returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two possible things going on here:

1. the values of `@a` and `CardId` *simply aren't matching*, due to not being quite what you expect; common reasons:

   - case sensitivity
   - whitespace
   - fixed width (`char`/`nchar`) vs dynamic width (`varchar`/`nvarchar`)
   - invisible characters (unicode characters or escape characters) in one of the two values
   - there simply isn't matching data for that value!
2. it *is* working, but you're looking in the wrong place

   - this is common when using file-based databases rather than dedicated servers - you need to be sure to look in the database file in the *executing* folder (often /bin/debug etc) rather than the *source* folder

To determine which, you might add `select @@rowcount;` after the `update` statement and use `var rowsUpdated = cmd.ExecuteScalar`. By reading this value, you can see how many rows were updated. If it is zero, then the first bullet applies; if it is non-zero, then the second bullet applies.

Assuming it is the first bullet, you'll need to look very carefully at the value of `momentcardid`, **including** any whitespace and hidden characters. `momentcardid.Length` would be a good place to start, but `momentcardid.ToCharArray()` would be the next step (and look carefully at every character)

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've figured it out :)

Answer (score 0):

Great point Mr. Marc Gravell

I've been struggling with this issue for over a week...

and for that exact reason, another thing to note is also the edit page/form. I had the same issue but noticed that this only occurred when I didn't include all the fields from the table, that are being updated in the edit form. So if your table consists of the fields (Id, CargoName, Jobdone) then your form should look like this:

```
<form asp-action="ProcessEdit">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"</div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Id" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Id" class="form-control" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="Id" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="CargoName" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="CargoName" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="Jobdone" class="control-label"></label>
                    <input asp-for="Jobdone" class="form-control" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" value="Edit" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </form>
```

I still don't know why exactly you need the other fields in order to get the UPDATE strSql to work, but this worked for me without having to change anything in my method.